# Flowchart write DSL for process

Tags: dsl, flowchart

I have a problem. I want to create a process with [Flowchart DSL](http://flowchart.js.org/). Unfortunately my process with `DSL` does not look even close as I want it.
How I have to write the `DSL`?

[image]

```
op1=>operation: Task1
op2=>operation: Task2
op3=>operation: Task3
op4=>operation: Task4
op5=>operation: Task5
op6=>operation: Task6
op7=>operation: Task7
op8=>operation: Task8
op9=>operation: Task9
op10=>operation: Task10
op11=>operation: Task11
e=>end: End|future:>http://www.google.com
para=>parallel: parallel tasks
para2=>parallel: parallel tasks2
para3=>parallel: parallel tasks3

op1->para3
para3->para(path1, bottom)
para3->para2
para(path1, bottom)->op3->op5
para2(path1, bottom)->op4->op5
```